# What is the shortcut for running java application in mac eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, shortcut

I get used to eclipse and know that ctrl+F9 is used for running java application in eclipse in windows. But now I switch to mac, and find that cmd+F9 is used for debug java application, so what is the short cut for running java application ?

Comment: It shows the shortcut keys in the menu when you drop down the `Run` menu. If you don't like the default then edit in preferences. `Eclipse -> Preferences -> -> General -> Keys`. You are probably missing pressing the `Fn` button in your command if you have a mac book pro and are adjusting the volume instead of pressing F11 :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Find the short for run: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

And debug : <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

Answer (score 35):

Notice, if you keyboard has multimedia functions, such as sound level control, brightness level etc etc. Then a lot of shortcuts using the F keys, such as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> will **not** fire the application specific shortcut, but rather the system-wide shortcut.

In that case, you will need to press <kbd>fn</kbd> as well, to fire the application specific shortcut. So in this case it would be: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

Comment: Fn + Cmd + Shift + F11 : Works well for me on Mac [Eclipse Mars]

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> works for me.

Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> will show a list of options on how you want to run your application.

Comment: Don't you think it's to long ? not so convenient ?

Answer (score 7):

To set your custom shortcut open <kbd>Eclipse</kbd> -> <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>General</kbd> -> <kbd>Keys</kbd> and search for `Run`. Scroll down a bit, select `Run` and set your custom binding in the textbox below. Finally click on apply and your ready to run :)

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> for Run

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> for Debug run