# Avoid prompt when launching Groovy scripts in Spring Tool Suite - Groovy Console and Groovy Script

Tags: eclipse, groovy, launcher, spring-tool-suite

In Spring Tool Suite (and I guess this applies to regular Eclipse, too), when I try to debug a Groovy script using keyboard (F11), it prompts me like this:

[image: Annoying popup]

I'd like to make it always run as Groovy Script in this case. I did some searching on the Net and also went through the Window / Preferences a few times, but could not find a way to select one or another to be a default (even on a per-script basis). Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're on linux and I'm not too familiar with the key bindings on that platform, but your best bet is to create a custom keybinding for running and debugging groovy scripts.  To do this, go to Preferences -> General ->Keys.  In the filter box, type *groovy script*. You should see 2 entries and looks like this (on mac):

[image: Key binding preferences page]

There should be shortcuts bound already, but if there aren't you can choose one and if there are, you can change it to something more your style.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - I will try that. On your machine, does the same popup appear? I'm more inclined to use F11 to run it, as that's the default for everything else.

Comment: F11 does not launch anything. I'm not sure what the equivalent key on Mac would be.

Comment: See this for probable cause of it not working - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141173/what-is-the-shortcut-for-running-java-application-in-mac-eclipse. If you try this, does it show a similar popup on your end?